# How do I make wp_localize_script variables available for child theme?

Tags: child-theme

I am trying to create a child theme and want to deregister the original javascript and enqueue my own. Its the original javascript of the theme but a bit different :)

The problem that I have is that in the parent theme a lot of variables are 'pushed' to JS using : wp_localize_script.

The variables that are loaded in parents functions.php are not available in my child themes javascript. And I am guessing that it is because of the load order. WordPress first loads the child functions.php then the parents. And thus, first load the javascript and then the variables. Plus when I enqueue my own javascript the script has a different name.

```
parent functions.php 

$translation_array = array ( .... ) ;

wp_enqueue_script('jscript_custom', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jscript.custom.js', array('jquery'), null, true);

wp_localize_script('jscript_custom', 'obj_jscript', $translation_array);


child theme functions.php

..
wp_dequeue_script( 'jscript_custom' );
..

wp_enqueue_script('jscript_custom_child', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/jscript.custom.js', array('jquery'), null, true);
```

so the variables from the parent theme are pushed to a javascript that is no longer available. And the child theme's script cannot have the same name as the parents theme.

Any ideas on how to solve this?
Thanks,
J

```
=== edit ===

**parent theme functions.php**

function parent_enqueue_scripts() {

    wp_enqueue_script('jscript_custom', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jscript_custom', array('jquery'), null, true);

    $translation_array = array(

        ... huge list of variables ...

        'tags_html' => $tags_html,
        'u' => $current_user->ID,
        'ui' => $current_user->display_name,
        'ul' => $current_user->user_nicename,
        'user_rewrite' => $wp_rewrite->author_base
    );

    wp_localize_script('jscript_custom', 'obj_jscript', $translation_array);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'parent_enqueue_scripts');




        ****child theme functions.php****

        function remove_parent_scripts() {
            wp_dequeue_script( 'jscript_custom' );
            }

        add_action('wp_print_scripts','remove_parent_scripts');


        function enqueue_parent_theme_style_and_js() {
            wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
            wp_enqueue_script('jscript_custom_child', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/jscript.custom.js', array('jquery'), null, true);

            }


    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_parent_theme_style_and_js' );

    .
```

Comment: you can manipulate the order that your enqueue function runs by changing the `add_action` priority. have you tested what happens if you dequeue the original and enqueue your own with the same handle?

Comment: I played with priority, but no success. The javascript won't load if I use exactly the same handle

Comment: I've just tested enqueueing, localizing, dequeueing, and re-enqueueing with the same handle and it worked. Add all of the relevant code from both the parent and child themes so we can see what it looks like.

Comment: Hi Milo, I have edited my original post and posted almost complete functions in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your child theme, set the priority on the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook to run later than the parent theme, and do your dequeue/re-enqueue there. Right now, your child theme code dequeues the original script on a later hook than your enqueue code.

```
function enqueue_parent_theme_style_and_js() {
    wp_dequeue_script( 'jscript_custom' );
    wp_enqueue_script('jscript_custom', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/jscript.custom.js', array('jquery'), null, true);
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_parent_theme_style_and_js', 30 );
```

Comment: Muchos gracias :)